# Trying to code discord bot to require certain role for specific commands

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.io

I'm a very weak coder, so please bear with me. The code pulls from var Discord = require('discord.io');

This is what I have for the code, but it doesn't work.

```
case 'refresh':

            if(cmd == 'refresh')
            if (message.member.hasPermissions("Mod")) {

                votedArr = [];
                bot.sendMessage({
                    to:channelID,
                    message: 'The votes have been refreshed!'
                });
            }
```

The error its giving me is this but I do not know how to solve it. 
*/
[image: Pic of Error]

Comment: Are you using Discord.js V11 or 12? Tip: You can check the version in package.json.

Comment: It says this when I checked.



  "discord.io": {
      "version": "https://github.com/woor/discord.io/tarball/gateway_v6",
      "integrity": "sha512-bIK3ETS+kdW7BhFNcTzEY3xFZWjm/7nvLEmhrsKqelpqT+RHlDeU1ZGNGnOTtjbFM77GqDzt9s/BVQnIUh3JYA==",
      "requires": {
        "cjopus": "^0.0.4",
        "tweetnacl": "^0.14.0",
        "ws": "^1.1.0"

Comment: discord.io is not discord.js, remove the tag.

Comment: What is `message`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the readonly [permissions](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Permissions?scrollTo=has) object.

Possible code you could use

```
if(message.member.permissions.has("Mod")){
    //Do things accordingly
}
```

The best reference for discrod.js documentation is the official documentation page, where you can find out about a lot of things: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/.

Hope this helps solve your problem.

Comment: That's not the error, OP is using discord.io, as such `message.member` is not a real value.

Comment: Is your bot just for one guild or is it for any guild?